# What does "parity" mean with regards to student loans?

Tags: loans, student-loan, terminology

I read in a newspaper that interest on part-time student loans was made the same as a full time student's loan in order to

> "achieve parity between part-time and full-time student loan programs"

Now I understand that "parity" means to make them equal, but does it have any financial meaning?

Comment: Whoever voted to close as off-topic: IMHO, this question is *not* off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the snippet of a quote, the word parity means equality.

Comment: then why didn't they just say "equality"?

Comment: There is no way to know why they used parity, but it is acceptable and not unusual.

Comment: There is a financial meaning of parity, but it doesn't apply here.

Comment: @Theta30: Because they wanted to make themselves seem more educated.